# Setting separate Orientation values in PhoneGap for iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, cordova

I am working on a PhoneGap based application for iOS, Android, etc.  For the iOS version, I would like to limit the available orientations for the iPhone and the iPad independently.

For example, the iPhone should only support portrait operation, while the iPad should support both portrait and landscape operation.

I have found the config.xml settings that allows me to set the available orientations for the iOS client as a whole, but not individually for the two form factors.

How can I configure the orientation support like this?  I will eventually want to do the same thing for Android as well.

Comment: I have the same problem. I would really appreciate to set the orientation independently (iPhone/iPad), but it seems like there is no such setting for it yet.

Answer (score 2):

After review of the Cordova documentation, it seems the only way to control the orientation like this is to configure it inside the Xcode Project that is created by running `cordova platform add iOS`.  The Cordova framework itself does not provide a mechanism for specifying separate orientations for the two devices.